# Oauth 2 for rails 2.3.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement Oauth2 but my rails version in 2.3.18, i am looking at doorkeeper, but it is not supporting my version, what are the other options i can use to implement Oauth2 in my rails application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doorkeeper gem does not support `rails 2.X.X` . You can cross check it's gemspecs file. It depend on `rails > 3.1.1` so you cannot use it in your rails app for version `2.x.x`. You can use https://github.com/intridea/oauth2 `intridea/oauth2` because it does not have dependency over rails version. Also it support `ruby-1.8.7` That is mostly used with `rails-2.x.x` . You can make a try to `intridea/oauth2`.

Comment: Thanks Nitin, with intridea/oauth2, is there any good documentation that you can suggest me? i checked on github but the could not find any. Thanks.